# How to copy a string "foobar" into clipboard in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I copy a simple string (for instance "foobar") to clipboard using JavaScript?

(jQuery is also accepted, since I already use it)

I've searched half an hour and still haven't found an easy solution, I can't believe it's so hard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: I'm a little bit puzzled. [Just entering your question title into google](https://www.google.de/search?q=How+to+copy+a+string+into+clipboard+in+JavaScript) yields pages of good results for me.

Comment: Did you even search?

Comment: **I proposed this answer to copy to clipboard:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/48371326/1715121

Answer (score 0):

Here you have:

```
function copyText(text) {
  var $input = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($input);
  $input.val(text).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $input.remove();
}

// Usage:
copyText("try!");
```

you can try this by pasting it in dev console and you'll have the text in your clipboard.

Comment: Thanks! But why does it only work in console but not in html+js? It's really weird. I also found a vanilla js version very similar to yours, and it's the same problem, only works in console

Comment: Yes I tried, it doesn't work, super strange. I've never seen anything like this

Comment: where is the data you want to copy?, has value of an input?